# Querying Swimming Distance from HealthKit

Tags: accelerometer, apple-watch, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I am having trouble getting my Apple Watch app to track users swimming distance and swimming strokes. I am querying from HealthKit, however I don't receive any samples when the workout configuration is set to pool/swimming. I am able to receive samples for running distance, calories, heart rate, and steps.

Is calculating swimming distance and strokes possible from using health kit, or does it require custom code using the Apple Watch accelerometer/GPS?

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar issues ... and finding it very difficult to determine which data types apple automatically generates and which have to be programmed by the developer.

Have you side loaded onto an AppleWatch or are you just trying to use the in-built journey sampling? I think if it's the latter, you won't get sample data for swimming, because Xcode is doing a walk or a cycle so won't generate swimming samples.

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Answering Questions Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have actually loaded it onto an Apple Watch and have not gotten any samples. However, I haven't actually tried it in a swimming pool. Rather, I was just shaking the watch (which worked to produce running and steps samples when configuration type is set appropriately). Perhaps it would work if I was actually in water when using it? If anyone has found success with this, I would much appreciate any guidance.